# Why does nuget.org have a version mismatch in the UI and the API?

Tags: nuget

There are many packages on nuget.org that have different information available via the UI and the v3 API. For example:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/4.2.0

This shows there are multiple versions available, including 4.2.0

However, to get the details of that version:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/microsoft.azure.eventhubs/4.2.0.json

Returns a 404. Other versions **are** found in the API, e.g.

https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/microsoft.azure.eventhubs/3.0.0.json

I'm looking for a reliable way to get at information from a specific version (e.g. release date), without having to screen scrape the UI. Is there a better place to look for this information, or to find out if a version is hidden for some reason?